# Upload and download .flv file PHP - Amazon S3

Tags: php, upload, header, amazon-s3, download

I'm working at a website that:

1) Uploads a .flv video from the computer of a user to a server (EC2 instance)
2) Moves this video from EC2 to S3
3) Allows users to download the file uploaded

Here comes the problem, if I upload and download different file formats such as .zip and .pdf it works fine, but if I download an .flv file this creates problems for every kind of player, it becomes impossible to read!!

This problem don't occours when I download the .flv video directly from S3 interface, it occours only when is downloaded from my website, this is the PHP code:

```
header("Content-type: Application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mycustomname.flv");
header("Content-Description: Download PHP");
readfile($file);
```

I don't know if this is related only to the download code but I think yes. Another question is why for every kind of file I download the browser can't estimate the time left?

Thank you!

Comment: do a byte-comparison of the flv you download from your server v.s. the one you'd originally uploaded. See what the differences are (e.g. garbage at the start or end of the downloaded copy).

Comment: have you tried another Content-type, like `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");` ?

Comment: I made a byte comparison, some charachters are different in the readable and in the non-readable file. But how can I fix this? PS. force-download does not work :(